# Can there be different Sharpe Ratios for the same index?

Tags: modern-portfolio-theory, capm

I am reviewing a fellow students paper, and it is argued in this paper that the Sharpe Ratio can differ based on which model is used to analyze the portfolio returns. Here a model based on the Arbitrage Pricing Theory which includes macroeconomic variables, and a classic CAPM model.

It is argued that the they calculate the Risk Premium based on the model, and then use this to calculate the Sharpe Ratio.

Is there any truth to this? As far as I know, from inspecting the Sharpe Ratio equation, there is only one Sharpe Ratio, period.

Thank you.

Comment: Are all of the inputs the same? Sharpe ratio involves a comparison to some “risk-free” asset. Could that asset be different in the two calculations?

Comment: There is ex post and ex ante CAPM. If you use CAPM or APT you compute expected return - not historical.

Comment: @Dave No, the risk-free is the same.

Comment: @AKdemy does this mean that the expected return, and therefore the Sharpe, can be different if some macroeconomic variables are included in the APT?

Answer (score 2):

One possible explanation is that Sharpe ratio involves a comparison to a “risk-free” asset. If the two calculations use different risk-free assets that have different returns, then the Sharpe ratios would differ.

Some people might consider US Treasury bonds to be risk-free. Some might consider a certificate of deposit to be risk-free. Some might consider a bank account to be risk-free. All of these have different returns and would lead to different Sharpe ratios.

Comment: The risk free is the same. Here they consider the 90-day T-Bill.

Answer (score 2):

While differences in Risk Free rates used can lead to differences, I do not think that the difference mentioned in the paper refers to differences in risk free rates. I would say that it discusses differences in ex-ante Sharpe ratios due to differences in models.

For example, [APT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrage_pricing_theoryhttps://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrage_pricing_theory) and [CAPM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capital_asset_pricing_model) will unlikely result in the same expected return of an asset. Hence, the ex-ante SR will be different, even if you use the same risk free rate.

[Wikipedia's page about SR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharpe_ratio#Definition) explains the difference betwenn ex-ante and ex-post SR, although I think it is quite self explanatory.

Comment: This seems reasonable. I am reading up on it now. But if these models produce very different SR, does it make sense to say that the model with higher SR is preferable then?

Comment: It's just a model after all. However, as long as the model provides some useful results (the computed expected return is a reliable estimate), it will still rank the securities. If the CAPM or APT make sense is really a separate question though.

Comment: Okay. In this example, the SR for the same index have SR = 0.8 with APT AND SR=1.9 with the CAPM. Does it make sense to say that the CAPM is the preferred model, for me it’s weird that the SR is so different.

Comment: What makes you think the CAPM is the preferred model? What if expected return and ex-post SR turns out to be exactly 1.9? After all, the only certain thing about the future is that it is uncertain. [Seekinalpha](https://seekingalpha.com/article/4144483-historical-s-and-p-sharpe-ratios-and-thoughts-on-2018) has a list of Sharpe ratios over time.

Comment: Yeah, that was my question. They argue in the paper that the CAPM is preferred since it is giving an higher SR, but I am trying to understand the logic behind that reasoning. But according to your comment, I guess the reasoning is flawed.